# KnockoutJS calling computed for each element in foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a problem i cannot figure out..
My example on JSbin: http://jsbin.com/wiwuwepe/1/edit

Basicly, in

```
    <script id="QuestionTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: QuestionText"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <!-- THIS IS WHERE I WANT COMPUTED FOR EACH SURVEYQUESTION -->
                <p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: QuestionTypeTemplate"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

QuestionTypeTemplate shows undefinded, although model for this is

```
     function SurveyQuestion(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.QuestionText = ko.observable(data.QuestionText);
        self.QuestionType = ko.observable(data.QuestionType);
        self.QuestionAnswers = ko.observableArray(data.QuestionAnswers);
        self.QuestionTypeTemplate = ko.computed(function () {
            /*
            if( self.QuestionType() == 0) {
              return "radio";
            } else if (self.QuestionType() == 1) {
              return "checkbox";
            }
            */
            return "This is what i want";
        }, self);
    }
```

Please, check full code on jsbin. Just uncomment that 1 line in QuestionTemplate script/html.
When I compare my example with http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html , I really cant find big difference, why that works, and why mine does not.

Comment: Actually, there's a pretty big difference. Notice how they _call_ `subtotal` in the binding because it's a `ko.computed`.

Comment: Also you don't seem to be mapping `data.SurveyQuestions` with `function SurveyQuestion(data)`. In other words you don't work with instances of `SurveyQuestion` but with the "raw" JSON. Using lodash: `self.SurveyQuestions = ko.observableArray(_.map(data.SurveyQuestions, SurveyQuestion));` (http://jsfiddle.net/7CP5T/)

Comment: Sergiu Paraschiv - if I could, I would mark your answer as the correct one!

Comment: Please write it up yourself and accept it :) I did not write it myself because I did not know if it was the only problem in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your Survey function

instead of this

```
self.SurveyQuestions = ko.observableArray(data.SurveyQuestions);
```

you need to use this

```
var questions = [];
for(i = 0 ; i<data.SurveyQuestions.length ; i++) {
   questions.push(new SurveyQuestion(data.SurveyQuestions[i]));
}
self.SurveyQuestions = ko.observableArray(questions);
```

Comment: From this, self.SurveyQuestions will be plain array, and will not work. It worked only,if I set self.SurveyQuestions =  ko.observableArray(); And push new SurveyQuestion(data.SurveyQuestions[i]) into that.

Comment: @Wish, it's still working without observable array http://jsbin.com/wiwuwepe/7/edit, but it's better to use observable array in this case, I updated my answer